# how to include loaders in webpack?

Tags: webpack, header, include

I am trying to include `Header.html` and also `footer.html` inside `index.html`. Because I am going to use these two files as common for all the pages. As my research webpack is not allowing to import files as

```
<!--#include file="header.html"-->
```

I've tried in grunt i was working fine . But how to do in webpack

this is my webpack version details

```
"name": "webpack-boilerplate",
"version": "1.0.0",
```

here is what i tried...
in my **webpack.config.js** file

```
{ 
   test: /\.html$/, 
   loader: 'html-loader' 
 }
```

in my **index.html** file

```
<body>
    require("html-loader!./file.html");
    <div class="banner">
        <h3>Banner 1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="banner banner2">
        <h3>Banner 2</h3>
    </div>
</body>
```

but its showing in page [image]

and this not for react. This is only for website and normal html..

so how to do this?

Comment: Are you using html-webpack-plugin to load the index.html file?

Comment: yes @lukas-reineke

Answer (score 19):

html-webpack-plugin supports templating with variables.

You can define the variables in your `webpack.config.js`

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './src/index.html',
    header: '<h1>hello world</h1>',
    fotter: '<b>Footer</b>'
}),
```

And put them in place in your index.html like so:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.header %>
        <!-- all your standard template here -->
        <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.footer %>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

To load the header and footer from normal HTML files requires an additional step and we use the built in `fs` node package for this (you don't have to install it).

```
let fs = require('fs');

const header = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/header.html');
const footer = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/footer.html');

module.exports = {

    // all of your normal config

    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/index.html',
        header: header,
        footer: footer,
      })
     ]
});
```

Now when you run webpack your HTML file will be injected in the positions you specified with the content of your header and footer files.

Comment: yeah sure @lukas

Comment: what is mean by  all of your normal config as you mentioned here? there i am confusing

Comment: @RND everything else you have in your webpack config, like `entry` `output` `module`

Comment: yeah but its not working.. i am searching how to import the header.html in index.html

Comment: can you see the image i uploaded in my question, you will get clear

Comment: @RND no, you are trying something completely different (which won't work). What is not working when you use my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170746/discussion-between-rnd-and-lukas-reineke).

Comment: Why not just use fs.readFileSync? Skips ALL of the promises mess. It was a oneliner for me and does exactly what OP wants.

Comment: @toxaq yea I might have overcomplicated that. Post it as an answer, even if OP doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Can just edit yours if you prefer? You led me to the solution,

Comment: have edited. Roll it back if you're not happy with that and I'll create a duplicate answer.

Comment: web.config.js, ->>
const header = fs.readFileSync('./src/header.html');

.plugins ->>

return new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        title: 'SJV Component Library',
        template: './src/index.html',
        inject: "body",
        header: header,
        favicon: 'assets/img/favicon.ico'
    });
  in index.html file i have header inside body. I tried putting class and id, so it matches with the partial , but no use.
What extra u need to do in index.html file or how should the header html look like ? Any example would be appriciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems to be promising in the beginning but there are some downsides. 1) It didn't work. 2) it might not require images (I wasn't able to test it), 3) I'm sure hotreloading wouldn't work.

Comment: @lukas-reineke is there any way to make this approach re-compile updates to the `header.html` file? If I write any changes, webpack continues delivering the original file. I have to re-start Webpack for it to notice any changes.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for this!

Comment: @lukas-reineke You wrote `fotter` and not `footer` by the way.

Comment: It's better. I'm going with fotter from now on. Long live fotter!