# Injecting HTML content into another file with Webpack

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I would like to inject some HTML from one file into another during Webpack bundling.

Let's say I have an index.html file like so:

```
//index.html
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello World</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

and another file with a bunch of icons:

```
//another.html
<symbol id="a" ...>...</symbol>
<symbol id="b" ...>...</symbol>
<symbol id="c" ...>...</symbol>
```

then I would like my "index.html" file to look like this after running webpack:

```
//index.html in bundle
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <symbol id="a" ...>...</symbol>
        <symbol id="b" ...>...</symbol>
        <symbol id="c" ...>...</symbol>
        <p>Hello World</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Basically, I just want whatever is in the files to be included in the body of my index.html. I have looked around all over the webpack ecosystem, but I can't find anything that does what I want.

The webpack config I have right now is using `html-webpack-plugin`:

```
{
    ....
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "index.html",
            inject: true,
        })
    ],
}
```

The files in question are taken from one of my dependencies, so I can't make any changes there or manually copy the content, but I do know the path to the folder that contains them, so I was hoping that I could use a loader/plugin to handle this for me.

Question: Is there a webpack loader/plugin that does this?

Comment: I just answered a very similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50130160/9083959