# Index.html with Webpack - How to put conditional code in it?

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I am uisng webpack with the "HtmlWebpackPlugin" and I want to put some google analytic code in but of course I only want it to be put in if it is on the production server.

Is there easy way I can do this?

Here is my "webpack.common.js"  (i have one for production, qa and dev).

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: ["@babel/polyfill", "./src/index.js"],
  output: {
    // filename and path are required
    filename: "main.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        // JSX and JS are all .js
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {}  
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {}
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(["dist"]),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html"
    }),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
   })
  ]
};
```

I updated to

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  const ga = argv.mode === 'production' ? './index-google.html' : 'index.html';
  return {
    entry: ['@babel/polyfill', './src/index.js'],
    output: {
      // filename and path are required
      filename: 'main.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          // JSX and JS are all .js
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader'
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'file-loader',
              options: {}
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'file-loader',
              options: {}
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/index.html'
      }),
      new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
      })
    ]
  };
};
```

but when I build I get

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 35:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (35:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| ReactDOM.render(
| 
>     <Provider routingStore={routingStore} domainStores={DomainStores} uiStores={uiStores}>
|       <Router history={history}>
|         <ErrorBoundary FallbackComponent={ErrorFallbackComponent}>
 @ multi ./src main[0]
```

babel file

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/env", "@babel/react"],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "transform-class-properties",
    "emotion"
  ]
}
```

I have an old repo what I modeled off my real code

https://github.com/chobo2/webpack-serve-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if it is a production version and thus serve what you like

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  filename: 'index.html',
  template: argv.mode === 'production' ? 'src/index-google.html' : 'src/index.html'
})
```

or take a look at this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50130160/10424385)

**EDIT**
I see that your webpack project is divided into dev, prod, common and config.
Delete HtmlWebpackPlugin from config and insert into dev and prod with the appropriate html file.

**dev**

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: "./src/index.html"
})
```

**prod**

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  filename: index.html,
  template: "./src/index-google.html"
})
```

I hope this solves the problem

Comment: I am trying your method but it does not seem to get my production variable.     new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: process.env.NODE_ENV=== 'production' ? "./src/index-google.html" :  "./src/index.html"
    }),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
   })

Comment: @chobo2 I prepared a working [example](https://github.com/tomik23/webpack-babel-corejs/tree/ga) If you run dev it will show alert ('dev'), running prod will generate a template index-google.html with alert ('prod')

Comment: hey, I updated my OP as I updated my webpack to look like yours but now I get an error when I try to build.

Comment: Show babel file. Or maybe you have a code on github?

Comment: Hey, I added my babel file.

Comment: Yep, I thought of the same thing yesterday and implemented.