# Webpack - How to include .html fragments into index.html with live reloading?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, webpack-dev-server, html-webpack-plugin

In PHP you can include file fragments for easy reusability. In the example below, I can include `header.php` and `footer.php`. This is very convenient because when I update `header.php`, the changes show up across all pages that use it:

```html
<html>
<body>

    <?php include 'header.php';?>

    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some more text.</p>

    <?php include 'footer.php';?>

</body>
</html>
```

I've successfully tried the approach [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50130160/2608515) by using `html-webpack-plugin`, but with one problem. See my config below:

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports = () => ({
    // ... lots of Webpack boilerplage

    module: {
        rules: [
            // ... js, sass, json, etc loaders
        ]
    },
    plugins: [

        //... 

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject: false,
            hash: true,
            template: "./static/index.html",
            header: fs.readFileSync(htmlPath + "/header.html"),
            footer: fs.readFileSync(htmlPath + "/footer.html"),
            filename: "index.html",
        }),
    ]
});
```

This allows me to include my `.html` files like this:

```html
<html>
<body>

    <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.header %>

    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some more text.</p>

    <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.footer %>

</body>
</html>
```

It works as expected at first glance, but the included `header.html` and `footer.html` files get "locked" in their initial state, and if I modify them I still get the original files, not the updated version. I have to shut down the Webpack dev server, then re-run it for changes to come through. I'm guessing this is because `fs.readFileSync()` only gets executed when Webpack is initialized, but not after a file change has been detected. What can I do to get these files to update?

Comment: If you're not married to using webpack, I suggest using express and pug templates instead. Templates are read from disk each time you request a URL, so just press F5 in the browser and you will see the change.

Comment: @ChrisG Ah, thanks for the suggestion, but this is for an existing project with 4 developers and nobody likes the guy that comes in to change up the whole framework :) I have to keep it in Webpack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to move the `fs.readFyleSync()` calls from the webpack.config into my index.html file, since the config file is only executed once when the dev server is fired up.

Here's my new webpack.config:

```js
// Get path to folder that contains HTML fragments
const folderPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/static/");

module.exports = () => ({
    // ... lots of Webpack boilerplate

    plugins: [
        //... 
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject: false,
            hash: true,
            template: "./static/index.html",
            filename: "index.html",
            HTML_PATH: folderPath // <- Now I only pass the folder path
        }),
    ]
});
```

... and then I read the files with `readFileSync()` inside the HTML:

```html
<html>
<body>

    <%= require("fs").readFileSync(htmlWebpackPlugin.options.HTML_PATH + "/header.html") %>

    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some more text.</p>

    <%= require("fs").readFileSync(htmlWebpackPlugin.options.HTML_PATH + "/footer.html") %>

</body>
</html>
```

Voilá! Hot-reloading HTML fragments!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for providing the solution using `readFileSync()`. It has been of great assistance to me.

In light of this, I'm considering making some improvements by incorporating the use of a `getter` alongside `readFileSync()` within the `webpack.config` file. This would simplify the process of inserting it into the HTML, eliminating the need to repeatedly input `require('fs').readFileSync()`. Instead, only `<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.fragment.mainHeader %>` would be required.

my webpack.config:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

/**
 * Automatically load HTML snippet files
 */
function getFragmentContentList() {
  const fragmentFolderPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/fragment');
  const fragmentFiles = fs.readdirSync(fragmentFolderPath).filter(item => {
    const itemPath = path.join(fragmentFolderPath, item);

    return fs.statSync(itemPath).isFile();
  });

  const fileContentList = {};

  fragmentFiles.forEach((filename) => {
    const fileFullPath = path.resolve(__dirname, pageFragmentPath, filename);
    const key = filename.split('.').shift();

    // use getter
    Object.defineProperty(fileContentList, key, {
      get() {
        return fs.readFileSync(fileFullPath, 'utf-8');
      },
    });
  });

  return fileContentList;
}

module.exports = () => ({
  // ...

  plugins: [
    // ... 
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: "index.html",
      fragment: getFragmentContenteList(), // <- Now
    }),
  ],
});
```

Then

```
<html>
<body>
  <header>
    <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.fragment.mainHeader %>
  </header>

  <p>Lorem</p>

  <footer>
    <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.fragment.mainFooter %>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

use libs version:

```
"webpack": "^5.88.2",
"webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
"webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.3",
```